# Are the Windows Azure SDK's MSBuild targets backwards compatible

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have projects that use the Azure SDK from back in version 2.0

As it appears that a new version comes out every second month or so (version 2.7 at time of writing), I wanted to know if it was safe to uninstall previous versions on an upgrade without breaking my msbuild files, or having to upgrade my projects.

ie, cause errors like:

`MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.7\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.`

Can I uninstall previous versions (like 2.5 from above) if I have 2.7 installed? Does the SDK inject MSBuild overrides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, installing a newer Azure version doesn't mean you no longer need to retain the existing targets. Keep any targets you have software built against, until such time as your build machines, development machines and software are upgraded to the newer version.

I demonstrated this for myself while setting things up on a new box and receiving the exact same error quoted in your question (2.7 target not found). I installed a newer Azure version, ending up with a 2.8 folder in that location, but the MSBuild error about not finding the 2.7 target persisted. Installing the newer version had not injected any MSBuild overrides or modified anything such that MSBuild would use the newer target.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I experienced the same and moved to installing *all* sdks as they came out for now.